# Show owned content in Media Library

Tags: 8, views, media

I am using Media Library from core, but users can choose media from any user.

How can I show only the content the user owns?

I have tried adding contextual filter in a view, but when I change  grid and table mode in Media Library, all content is showed again.

Comment: How did you implement the contextual filter?

Comment: I have edited `/admin/structure/views/view/media_library/edit/widget` and `/admin/structure/views/view/media_library/edit/widget_table`.

I have add in both the same contextual filter: "Authored by" -> "Fix value" -> "Id from user logged".

Now, I have not seen any content.